# Launching Puppeteer with chrome browser

Tags: puppeteer

I was working with puppeteer to launch the chrome browser but i was unable to launch it. Can anyone could help me with the correct way of selecting the path for chrome.exe file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the path of the folder where the chrome.exe is present.

Suppose chrome.exe is located in a folder having the following path:

C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application

Then, the correct way of selecting folder will be:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application'
  headless: true
});
```

(Reason for using double backslash is that backslash is used to escape character.)

In Linux or Mac OS, suppose the path where chrome located is:

/usr/bin/google-chrome

Then,  the correct way of selecting folder will be:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
    headless: true
});
```